# save single string to array separate by multi space in file text java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a java beginner and I'm doing a small project about dictionary, now I want to save word and translate mean in file, because my native language often have space like `chicken` will be `con gà` so, I must use other way, not by space, but I really don't know how to do that, a word and it translation in one line, separate by "tab", mean multi space like `chicken con gà` now I want to get 2 words and store it in my array of Words which I created before, so I want to do something like

```
w1=word1inline;
w2=word2inline;
Word(word1inline,word2inline);(this is a member of array);
```

please help me, thanks a lot, I just know how to read line from file text, and use `split` to get word but I am not sure how to read by multi space.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class docfile {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String readLine;
        ArrayList<String>str=new ArrayList<>(String);
        try {
            File file = new File("text.txt");
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((readLine = b.readLine()) != null) {
                str.add()=readLine.split("  ");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Split uses regex. You can create a regex with multiple spaces: `split("\\s{2,}")`. This will split on 2-or-more spaces.

Comment: You could use a different character as your delimiter. I prefer to use a semicolon `;` or a comma `,`. Then you could just use `split(';')` or `split(',')`

Comment: Also, `split` returns an array, so `str.add()=readLine.split("  ");` won't work because the `str` array list expects a string. You might want to use a dictionary ([`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)).

Answer (score 0):

If you stick to using tabs as a separator, this should work:

```
package Application;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String line;
        ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            File file = new File("text.txt");
            BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
                for (String s : line.split("\t")) {
                    str.add(s);
                }
            }

            str.forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a properties file?

**dict.properties**:

```
chicken=con gá
```

**Dict.java**:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Dict {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties dict = new Properties();
        dict.load(Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("dict.properties")));
        System.out.println(dict.getProperty("chicken"));
    }
}
```

Output:

> con gá

Answer (score 0):

If your line is like this `chicken con gà` you can use `indexof()` method to find the first space in the string.

Then you can substring each word by using `substring()` method.

```
    readLine = b.readLine();
    ArrayList<String>str=new ArrayList<>();

    int i = readLine.indexOf(' ');
    String firstWord = readLine.substring(0, i);
    String secondWord = readLine.substring(i+1, readLine.length());

    str.add(firstWord);
    str.add(secondWord);
```